# Can I play iOS games with keyboard and mouse from my PC?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, ios, airplay

Some games don't really lend themselves to either touch screen input or, as of iOS13, controller input. Yet, when available, I'd prefer getting the iOS version for the sake of mobile availability on travels.

So I considered streaming the games from iOS to my PC while I am at home, which works at acceptable frame rates with AirPlay receivers like LonelyScreen.

However, it doesn't fix the controls issue. Is there any way go mirror the PC-Keyboard and Mouse to iOS? Preferably using some "bi-directional" feature of AirPlay, if such a thing exists.

Comment: Search Bing or Google __play iOS games on Windows PC__, I found "How to Play iOS Games on Pc.  Firstly, you should download iPadian....", hope this helps.

Comment: @vssher Simulators don't apply. I need to be able to play the game on the iPad, but with the screen and input devices of the PC. iPadian doesn't have access to the App Store, never mind having access to my savegame when using the tablet on the go. With this solution I might as well just buy the windows version of the game.